# Using ArcPy to set Processing Extent to “Default”

Tags: arcpy, extents

I have an ArcPy routine that will often fail if the processing extents are not set to "Default" but I can't find any documentation on how that is done. I've tried the obvious arcpy.env.extent = "DEFAULT" but it doesn't seem to change anything. Also tried arcpy.env.extent="MAXOF".

While on the topic of processing extents, will setting the processing extent on the menu of an arcpy routine also set the extents accessed under Geoprocessing>Environment>etc?

Comment: One question per Question, please.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere on the documentation where you can set the extent to default.  Default just uses the calculated extent from the tools that run.  I would assume it would be similar to not setting an extent, that is not setting arcpy.env.extent.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/output-extent.htm

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/extent.htm

Extents are inherited on a nested system.  You can set environment settings at the global level which can be overridden by a model or script and finally can be overridden on a tool.  So starting at the highest level should flow all the way through, unless you override at a lower level, such as a tool.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/environments/environment-levels-and-hierarchy.htm